# Question about grep with regex, unexpected output

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, grep, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use `grep "regex" path_to_file`, and this is my approach:

```
grep "(\/bbcswebdav\/.*_2)" file.txt
```

(escaping `/` is what [regex101](https://regex101.com/) promoted me to do)

There were no outputs in the console.

However, when I tested the regular expression on regex101, I received my desired output.

The desired results here are all strings from `/bbcswebdav/` to `_2`, e.g. `/bbcswebdav/pid-816174-dt-content-rid-8436387_2/xid-8436387_2`

But when I do

```
grep "/bbcswebdav/.*_2" file.txt
```

The same goes with `grep -E`, suggested in the comments.

```
grep -E "/bbcswebdav/.*_2" file.txt
```

the output will be very messy, in this case: `<li><a href="/bbcswebdav/pid-816174-dt-content-rid-8436387_2/xid-8436387_2" target="_blank"><img src="/images/ci/ng/cal_year_event.gif" alt="file">&nbsp;5 diversity－name.pptx</a>`

Therefore my questions are:

1. What might have gone wrong in my command line input?
2. What are some better alternative regex? (or approach, in general)

Thank you.

Comment: `grep` uses basic regular expressions by default, `()` has no special meaning. Use `grep -E` for extended regular expressions.

Comment: But there's no need to use a capture group in the first place. Also, you don't have to escape slash in `grep`.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't `()` used to extract the desired section of the output? If I use `grep "/bbcswebdav/.*_2" file.txt`, the result will be super messy, in my case  `<li><a href="/bbcswebdav/pid-816174-dt-content-rid-8436387_2/xid-8436387_2" target="_blank"><img src="/images/ci/ng/cal_year_event.gif" alt="file">&nbsp;5 diversity－name.pptx</a>`

Comment: So, does it work for `grep -E` ?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It worked with `grep -E`, but not as expected (the one displayed in the second image)

Comment: @IanHsiao if you want to extract the text matched by the regex, use `-o` option as well. By default, `grep` displays the whole matching line. Also, I'd suggest to use `/bbcswebdav/[^"]*_2` to avoid getting wrong results if you have `_2` later in the line. Or better yet, use html/xml parsing tool instead of regex.

Comment: @Sundeep yes, this is related. Thanks!